# Subspace topologies are equal on an equicontinuous subset

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, filters

In our class, we have already proven that:

> Let $Y$ is a metric space, $X$ a topological space and $H \subseteq
>  C(X,Y)$ equicontinuous and $\Psi$ a filter base on $H$. Suppose that $pr_x(\Psi) \to
>  \phi(x)$ for all $x \in X$.
>
> Then, the function $x \mapsto \phi(x)$ is continuous and $\Psi
> \to\phi$ in the compact open topology.

Now, it is claimed that the following is an immediate corollary of this theorem:

> If $Y$ is a metric space and $H \subseteq C(X,Y)$ is equicontinous,
>   then $(\mathcal{T}_c)_H = (\mathcal{T}_p)_H$ (the former is the compact open topology, the latter the pointwise topology (i.e. subspace topology on product)

I can't however see how this follows. We proved that $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_c$, and one inclusion follows from this. But the other one should follow from the theorem above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it work if we show that $1: (H, (\mathcal{T}_p)_H) \to (H, (\mathcal{T}_c)_H): x \mapsto x$ is continuous? Then, the inclusion follows. So, let $\phi \in H$. We show that $1$ is continuous in $\phi$. For this, let $F$ be a filter on $H$ s.t. $F \to \phi$ in $(\mathcal{T}_p)_H$. Can we proceed with such a proof and use the given theorem somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, following your own suggestion, let $\mathrm{id}: (H, (\mathcal{T}_p)_H) \to (H, (\mathcal{T}_c)_H)$ be defined by $\mathrm{id}(f) = f$ for all $f \in H$. The fact that trivially $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_c$ on $Y^X$ and hence on all subspaces too (singletons are compact), $\mathrm{id}$ is an open map.

The facts you have been given show its continuity: let $f \in H$ and suppose that for some filterbase on $H$, $\Psi \to f$ pointwise (i.e. in $(\mathcal{T}_p)_H$), which means that $\pi_x[\Psi] \to \pi_x(f) = f(x)$ for all $x$. As $\Psi \to f$ in $\mathcal{T}_c$ in that case (I don't use the first fact as $f \in H$ already means that $f$ is continuous), $\mathrm{id}[\Psi] \to \textrm{id}(f)$ in $(H, (\mathcal{T}_c)_H)$, and as continuity is determined by convergence of filters or filter bases, $\mathrm{id}$ is continuous, which immediately implies the identity of topologies.

We could have extended it too $K = \overline{H}$, the pointwise closure of $H$, which is still equicontinuous, and we'd have shown that $K$ is also the compact-open closure of $H$ this way.

Comment: I'm sorry. But does this answer the question? In my post it says that this was already proven. I need help on the other statement.

Comment: I need to prove that $(\mathcal{T}_c)_H \subseteq (\mathcal{T}_p)_H$ though, given the theorem I mentioned at first. In the comments above, I wrote a possible attack strategy (don't know for sure if it works)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last remark? And ideally, include an answer that uses the attack strategy as mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: Another question: how do you interpret the phrase $\Psi$ is a filterbasis on $H$? Does this simply mean $\Psi \subseteq \mathcal{P}(H)$, but that the filter it generates is a filter on $C(X,Y)?$ (recall that we work in the space of continuous functions)

Comment: @Math_QED a filterbase on $H$ is just a set of subsets of $H$, and I consider the filter on the power set of $H$ that it generates. As $H \subseteq C(X,Y)$ all these sets only contain continuous functions and convergence is in the subspace topology.

Comment: So you think the convergence is in the subspace topology? I.e. $\Psi \to \phi$ should be read as convergence in $(\mathcal{T}_c)_H$?

Comment: @Math_QED yes, the subspace topology, or in $C(X,Y)$, which is the same.