# Coincidence of two topologies

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space.
$F$ is a set of mapping from $X$ into itself, Then:

If $F$ is equicontinuous on $X$ then on $F$ the topology of pointwise convergence coinsides with the compact-open topology on $F$.

How can I prove this? many thanks for any help

Comment: Check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2792723/4280)

Comment: Or see Kelly *General Topology* p 232, Thm 15.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

By the notation $[A,B]$, where $A,B \subseteq X$, I will mean $\{f: X \to X: f[A] \subseteq B\}$. The pointwise topology on a set of functions $F$ then has as base all sets of the form $[A,U] \cap F$, where $A$ is finite and $U$ is open, and the compact-open topology on $F$ has as base all sets of the form $[K,U]\cap F$ where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open. As all finite subsets are compact, it's clear that the pointwise topology is always coarser than (i.e. a subset of) the compact-open topology. So to show the reverse inclusion for an equicontinuous family $F$, we need to show the following fact:

> For all compact $K$ and open $U$ and $f \in [K,U] \cap F$ there is a finite subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f \in [A,U]\cap F \subseteq [K,U]\cap F$.

Some ideas on how to do this: First find $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B(f[K],\varepsilon) \subseteq U$ by compactness of $f[K]$ and openness of $U$.
Then apply equicontinity of $F$ to find some $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,x') < \delta$ always implies $d(g(x),g(x'))< \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ (or some other convenient fraction of $\varepsilon$), globally on $X$ or at least on $K$, depending on your definition of equicontinity, and cover $K$ with finitely many balls of radius $\frac{\delta}{2}$. Use their centres as the finite $A$. Use triangle inequalities to show the inclusion we need.

Comment: Brandma tank you very much